# Better way to plot Gender count using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am making a graph to plot Gender count for the time series data that look like following data. Each row represent hourly data of each respective patient.

| HR | SBP | DBP | Sepsis | Gender | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 98 | 115 | 85 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 109 | 115 | 75 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 94 | 135 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 97 | 100 | 70 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 85 | 120 | 80 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 88 | 115 | 75 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 93 | 125 | 85 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 78 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 115 | 140 | 110 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 98 | 140 | 110 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

This is my code:

```
gender = df_n['Gender'].value_counts()
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
ax = gender.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, color="c")
ax.set_title("Bar Graph of Gender", y = 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Gender')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of People')
ax.set_xticklabels(('Male', 'Female'))

for rect in ax.patches:
    y_value = rect.get_height()
    x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
    space = 1
    label = format(y_value)
    ax.annotate(label, (x_value, y_value), xytext=(0, space), textcoords="offset points", ha='center', va='bottom')    
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Now what is happening is the code is calculating total number of instances (0: Male, 1: Female) and plotting it. But I want to plot the total males and females, not the total number of 0s and 1s, as the Same patient is having multiple rows of data (as per P_ID). Like how many patients are male and how many are female?

Can someone help me out? I guess maybe sns.countplot can be used. But I don't know how.

Thanks for helping me out >.<

__________ Udpate ________________

How I can group those Genders that are sepsis (1) or no sepsis (0)?

__________ **Update 2** ___________

So, I got the total actual count of Male and Female, thanks to @Shaido.
[image: male female count]

In the whole dataset, there are only 2932 septic patients. Rest are non-septic. This is what I got from @JohanC answer.

[image: graph]

Now, the problem is that as there are only 2932 septic patients, by looking at the graph, it is assumed that only 426 (251 Male) and (175 Female) are septic patients (out of 2932), rest are non-septic. But this is not true. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does using `groupby` give you what you want? For example, `df.groupby('P_ID')['Gender'].first().value_counts()`.

Comment: I would use unique() to get all the P_ID and then select the first appearance of each P_ID to get the gender. Not sure if it is the best way to go though

Comment: @Shaido yes it gave me what I want. Thanks

Comment: Maybe 2932 is the number of septic rows, containing the same patients multiple times? Or some rows contain something else than 0 and 1 (e.g. the letter 'O')? You could try `df_n.describe()` to find out whether the columns are strictly numeric, as well as their min/max.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example for selecting the unique IDS, it looks ugly so there is probably a better way, but it works...

```
import pandas as pd
# example of data:
data = {'gender': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# get all unique ids:
ids = set(df.id)
# Go over all id, get first element of gender:
g = [list(df[df['id'] == i]['gender'])[0] for i in ids]

# count genders, laze way using pandas since the rest of the code also assumes a dataframe for plotting:
gender_counts = pd.DataFrame(g).value_counts()
# from here you can use your plot function.

# Or Counter
from collections import Counter
gender_counts = Counter(g)
# You have to create another method for plotting the gender.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by 'P_ID' and take the first row for each of them (supposing a 'P_ID' has only one gender and only one sepsis). Then you can call `sns.countplot` on that dataframe, using gender for `x` and sepsis for `hue` (or vice versa). You can rename the values in the columns to show their names in the legend and in the tick labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''
HR|SBP|DBP|Sepsis|Gender|P_ID
92|120|80|0|0|0
98|115|85|0|0|0
93|125|75|1|1|1
95|130|90|1|1|1
102|120|80|0|0|2
109|115|75|0|0|2
94|135|100|0|0|2
97|100|70|1|1|3
85|120|80|1|1|3
88|115|75|1|1|3
93|125|85|1|1|3
78|130|90|1|0|4
115|140|110|1|0|4
102|120|80|0|1|5
98|140|110|0|1|5
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delimiter='|')
# new df: take Sepsis and Gender from the first row for every P_ID
df_per_PID = df.groupby('P_ID')[['Sepsis', 'Gender']].first()
# give names to the values in the columns
df_per_PID = df_per_PID.replace({'Gender': {0: 'Male', 1: 'Female'}, 'Sepsis': {0: 'No sepsis', 1: 'Sepsis'}})
# show counts per Gender and Sepsis
ax = sns.countplot(data=df_per_PID, x='Gender', hue='Sepsis', palette='rocket')
ax.legend(title='')  # remove title, as it is clear from the legend items
ax.set_xlabel('')
for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars)
# ax.margins(y=0.1)  # make some extra space for the labels
ax.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot from aggregated dataframe]

Comment: thanks for the amazing answer. Your answers always worked for me. The code kind of worked, but there is an issue. I am updating the question. Please have a look at it.